# What happens in the ending of Batman Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm confused about the ending of Arkham City:

> Does Joker really die at the end of Batman Arkham City?

Is it a ploy?  At the end during the credits you can hear a voice mail he left you three hours earlier, does this have any bearing on the situation?

Comment: What do you get the super villain who has everything for a baby shower? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxFvYHf49EY

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say, no, he doesn't.

> The Joker's such an iconic Batman villan, there's no way to kill him.  The Joker's an integral part of Batman's universe.  As with every comic book character, he can appear to die and then show up in the next issue/episode/sequel as if nothing has happened.

I would like to note, however, that this game was [Mark Hamill](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000434/)'s  [last performance](http://www.comicsalliance.com/2011/10/19/mark-hamill-retires-the-joker-arkham-city/) as the Joker.

Comment: Actually Mark Hamill [somewhat recanted on that](http://multiplayerblog.mtv.com/2011/10/29/mark-hamill-not-done-with-joker-batman-arkham-city-and-killing-joke-tweets/). I pretty much never believe him at this point.

Comment: Huh.  Well, I'm looking forward to more Joker(s) with his voice then.  I was sad when he announced he was calling it quits.

Comment: Also, there's a very convenient period there where Batman's knocked out. You would think that Joker or Clayface would have done *something* in that time.

Comment: For an interesting look at this subject (NSFW language), watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PlwDbSYicM).

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely going to be a sequel to Arkham City, if you've finished all the side missions and the story mode, there are many references, the Azrael Side Mission, the Scarecrow easter egg. Also, Harley's pregnent; And it's obviously going to be the Joker's baby.That being said, they can't have a Batman game without the Joker, maybe not Joker Sr, but Joker Jr.

Comment: Actually, in the Harley Quinn's Revenge DLC it's revealed she's not pregnant after all, and it was a false positive. Also in that DLC there are posters around for CADMUS, which if you do your research could possibly point to cloning technologies (perhaps the one that dies is a clone?)